# how to call jquery dialog using RegisterStartupScript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following vb.net and it is working great

```
Public Shared Sub createAlert(ByVal page As Page, ByVal msg As String)
    msg = msg.Replace(vbCrLf, "\n").Replace("'", "\'")
    page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType, "clientScript", "<script language='javascript'>alert('" & msg & "');</script>")
End Sub
```

Now I would like to implement this http://jsfiddle.net/WrdM9/2/ . it is a jquery dialog with auto close after 3 seconds

I have tried the following to no luck
What am I doing wrong?

```
Public Shared Sub AlertAutoClose(ByVal page As Page, ByVal msg As String)
    Dim sScript As String
    sScript = "<script src=""js/jquery.js"">$(document).ready(function(){$('#dialog').html('some message');});"
    sScript += "$(document).ready(function(){$('#dialog').dialog({"
    sScript += "autoOpen: true,"
    sScript += "show: ""blind"","
    sScript += "hide: ""explode"","
    sScript += "modal: true,"
    sScript += "open: function(event, ui) {"
    sScript += "setTimeout(function(){"
    sScript += "$('#dialog').dialog('close');                "
    sScript += "}, 3000);"
    sScript += "}"
    sScript += "});});</script>"

    msg = msg.Replace(vbCrLf, "\n").Replace("'", "\'")
    page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType, "Script", sScript)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

When you reference a script file in your script tag like src="js/jquery.js", what's in between the script tag will not be executed and it's technically illegal.  So you just need to break that out into a separate script tag.  This will work:

```
<script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('test');
</script>
```

This will not:

```
<script src="js/jQuery.js">
    alert('test');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first problem is whne you type in  you have 2 double quotes. I think it needs to be

```
<script src=\"js/jquery.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\">$(document).ready(function(){$....
```

Make sure you are also passing the right path for the Jquery file.

You can also exclude the jquery by adding the jquery script on your aspx/html page markup. And you would change your string to

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">$(document).ready(function(){$
```

Answer (score 0):

I change the code to this. and it is working now

```
sScript = "<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js""></script>"
sScript += "<script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"">$('#dialog1').html('" & msg & "');"
sScript += "$('#dialog1').dialog({"
sScript += "autoOpen: true,"
sScript += "show: ""blind"","
sScript += "hide: ""explode"","
sScript += "modal: true,"
sScript += "open: function(event, ui) {"
sScript += "setTimeout(function(){"
sScript += "$('#dialog1').dialog('close');"
sScript += "}, 3000);"
sScript += "}"
sScript += "});</script>"
msg = msg.Replace(vbCrLf, "\n").Replace("'", "\'")
page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType, "Script", sScript)
```