# How to call javascript method when user clicks on button(not on page_loadcomplete)?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

Tried Google but couldn't find my answer, So posting it here.

SS is attached in last. When the user clicks on download button, some actions performed on backend i.e. file transfer and when the process is completed, it changes the label text of "Total"

I want to change the label text of the div.

I have tried "RegisterStartupScript" also in place of "RegisterClientScriptBlock"

But didn't work

Tried by setting innerHtml from c# also didn't work

C#

```
protected void btnrepeat()
{
     //my code for load balancing
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "myScript21211", "UpdateServerMax('" + server1max + "')", true);
     //LabelServer1Max.InnerHtml = server1max.ToString();
}
```

JavaScript

```
function UpdateServerMax(server1Max) {
     alert("njk");
     LabelServer1Max.innerHTML = server1Max;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 tile_stats_count" style="margin-bottom: -1%">
<br />
<span class="count_top"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Total </span>
<div class="count" id="LabelServer1Max" runat="server">
            4,567</div>
</div>
```

Also tried removing runat="server" from div.

Here is the SS what i want to change. https://ibb.co/kZ2Zvk

The 4th label says "Total".

Comment: LabelServer1Max is not at all available to the JS - try `document.getElementById("LabelServer1Max").innerHTML` or `$("#LabelServer1Max").html(...)`

Comment: No server side code can help you detect page is loaded at client side. You have to do it on the client. Check `onLoad()` docs here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp

Comment: But even alert is also not being called

Comment: See my updated comment. LabelServer1Max is just a string in an ID - I only answered the JS part.

Comment: @MirkoVukušić The c# function is called at user interaction i.e. when clicked on button, so no page is reloaded. And I want to change the text on the page
Here, what I want to change is just the 4th label says "Total"

https://ibb.co/kZ2Zvk

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30768915/295783

Answer (score 0):

You can update the value from C# after the Page_Load event.It can be somethig like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  LabelServer1Max.Text= server1Max;
}
```

or after the Page_LoadComplete Event

```
void  Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LabelServer1Max.Text= server1Max;
}
```

Add it to your .cs file.

Comment: Corrected my question. Read it again.
I want to change the label when user clicks on button.

Comment: either you put ***onclick*** attribute on the button and attach a function call with that like ***<button onclick="UpdateServerMax()">Text</button>*** with the definition of UpdateServerMax() funtion in the bottom of the design page or you can use EventListener service and attach the click event to the button and change the value when the event fires.If the server1max value is fetched from server you need to use AJAX to bring that value.Hope I helped.

Comment: But it works in this:

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          if (chkcount > 3)
            {

                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "lol", "javascript :chkboxalert()", true);
            }
    }